# SO opens image in same window without warning while writing a comment

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, comments

When writing an answer and do anything that would result in another page to be loaded in the same window we get a dialog box `Leave Site? Changes you made may not be saved.` So we don't accidentally lose what we have written.

But while writing a comment and click on an image that is within the question, this image is opened in the same window without any warning and the whole comment is lost.

That happened to me three times in a row until I realized why that happened:  the question had an image with a large white area at the bottom at which I clicked to bring the window back to the foreground.

Comment: Yep.  Comments don't have the same page protections as answers do, by design.

Comment: @RobertHarvey that's intended? That's quite annoying and frustrating if you copy a link and/or text from another site and loose your whole comment due to that.

Comment: Comments are third-class citizens.  If you want the page navigation protections that an answer affords, post an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I agree that this is quite annoying and I have often lost comments with 200+ characters because of this. A simple solution: always use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> to open links. That's a good practice and I mostly open links with this way.

The second, simpler solution is, yes!, userscripts. [SOX](https://stackapps.com/q/6091) (<kbd>[install dev version](https://github.com/soscripted/sox/raw/dev/sox.user.js)</kbd>) has an option in the comments section to add a confirmation dialog when navigating away on pages whilst still typing a comment:

[image]

The next time you try to exit while typing a comment, there will be a dialog to warn you.

Comment: `A simple solution: always use CTRL to open links.` I most of the time already do that. It is more about if you click on a white area in the window where you are currently writing a comment to bring it back in front, and that white area happens to part of an image. But SOX seems to be a good solution.

Comment: I made a userscript just for this - [Lightbox Images](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/LightboxImages.user.js) simply opens any image in a lightbox (works in chat too). No more navigating away.